# What causes laser speckles to "apparently" move when you film the projection of a laser beam on a hard surface?

Tags: electromagnetism, laser

I've been trying to investigate a phenomenon in which laser speckles seem to move when you film their projection on a hard surface. Accordingly, I have 2 questions:
-Is this phenomenon observationally induced or do the speckles "really" move?
-Is there a technical term for this phenomenon?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe the dynamical fluctuations are too fast to be processed by the human eye?

Comment: Have you done a search of this site for [speckles laser](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=speckles+laser)?

Comment: Or search for digital speckle interferometry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_speckle_pattern_interferometry